# Filter a list of sets with specific criteria

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of sets:

```
a = [{'foo','cpu','phone'},{'foo','mouse'}, {'dog','cat'}, {'cpu'}]
```

Expected outcome:

I want to look at each individual string, do a count and return everything `x >= 2` in the original format:

```
a = [{'foo','cpu'}, {'foo'}, {'cpu'}]
```

Here's what I have so far but I'm stuck on the last part where I need to append the new list:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
for a_set in a:
    # Created a counter to count the occurrences a word
    counter.update(a_set)
result = []
for a_set in a:
    for word in a_set:
        if counter[word] >= 2:
            # Not sure how I should append my new set below.
            result.append(a_set)
            break
print(result)
```

Comment: What's your desired output? `a = [{'foo','cpu'}, {'foo'}, {'cpu'}]` is not  result of `x < 2`.

Comment: Your problem isn't "append[ing] the new list"; it is making the new set(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

Build a counter then iterate over the original list of sets and filter items with <2 counts, then filter any empty sets:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

a = [{'foo','cpu','phone'},{'foo','mouse'}, {'dog','cat'}, {'cpu'}]

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(list, a)))
res = list(filter(None, ({item for item in s if c[item] >= 2} for s in a)))

print(res)
Out: [{'foo', 'cpu'}, {'foo'}, {'cpu'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just appending the original set. So you should create a new set with the words that occur at least twice.

```
result = []
for a_set in a:
    new_set = {
            word for word in a_set
            if counter[word] >= 2
    }
    if new_set:  # check if new set is not empty
            result.append(new_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use the following short approach based on *sets* intersection:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [{'foo','cpu','phone'},{'foo','mouse'}, {'dog','cat'}, {'cpu'}]
c = Counter([i for s in a for i in s])
valid_keys = {k for k,v in c.items() if v >= 2}
res = [s & valid_keys for s in a if s & valid_keys]

print(res)   # [{'cpu', 'foo'}, {'foo'}, {'cpu'}]
```